# Sheaf cohomology of certain line bundle

Tags: algebraic-geometry

First of all I am sorry if this question is duplicate. I tried to search it but didn't succeed.

Let $X$ be a blowing up of projective plane $\mathbb{P}_k^2$ at one point and $L$ be an exceptional divisor. How can one compute cohomologies of $\mathcal{O}_X(-L)$? I am trying to check that they are all zero.

The general theory suggests that from the exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X(-L)\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_L\rightarrow0$$

we have the exact sequence of cohomologies

$$0\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-L))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_L)\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-L))\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^1(X, \mathcal{O}_L)\rightarrow...$$

and from the known fact $H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=0$ we obtain the exact sequence

$$0\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-L))\rightarrow H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)\rightarrow H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_L)\rightarrow H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-L))\rightarrow0$$

in which $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)=k$ and $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_L)=k$. I guess that the map from $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ to $H^0(X, \mathcal{O}_L)$ is injective which means that $H^0(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-L))=H^1(X,\mathcal{O}_X(-L))=0$ but I have some difficulties to justify this fact.

How can I finish these computations? (I mean using this approach)

Comment: 2 clarifying questions: By "$L$ is an exceptional line," do you mean $L$ is the exceptional divisor (the $\mathbb{P}^1$ over the point you blew up)? What is $\mathcal{O}_X(-L)$?

Comment: @ KReiser   Yes, $L$ is the exceptional divisor. $\mathcal{O}_X(-L)$ is just dual to $\mathcal{O}_X(L)$, which is invertible sheaf defined by the divisor $L$.

Comment: For any connected variety $Y$ we have $H^0(Y,O_Y)=k$, the constant functions. Now restriction from $X$ to $L$ maps the constant functions on $X$ isomorphically to the constant functions on $L$. So the middle map in your 4-term sequence is indeed an isomorphism, as you require.

Comment: @user200000: $\mathcal{O}_X(-L)$ is a negetive degree line bundle. so $h^0 (X, \mathcal{O}_X(-L)) = 0.$ now using the comment of Asal Beag Dubh, you can conclude.